# Remove Proxy Setting in Batch File

Tags: proxy, internet, internet-explorer, batch-file

I want to create a batch file to remove Internet Explorer proxy settings check box. Not to grey it out - but to remove IE from using proxy settings. Anyone got any scripts for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting proxy settings:

- .reg file:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
  "ProxyServer"="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"
  "ProxyOverride"="<local>"
  "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
  ```
- .vbs file:

  ```
  set wshshell = createobject("Wscript.shell")
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer","192.168.001.250:80"
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride","<local>"
  wshshell.popup "Proxy Example set.",3,"Messagebox"
  ```
- but why not use Group Policy?

Comment: I can add the use of the proxy server, but in GP how do you remove the use of proxy?

Comment: just unchecked the box "Enable Proxy Settings" in GPO? If that doesn't help, try making the change in the 'User Config>Windows Settings>IE Maintenance>Connection settings.

Select 'Import the current connection settings from this machine' Choose LAN Settings and modify them to what you need. I would leave all boxes unchecked. Apply the settings and run a GPupdate /force.

Check the logs for any errors and test on a client PC.

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer and Google chrome both shares same proxy settings. So if we change setting in internet explorer, then it also effects in Google chrome. We can change proxy setting from CMD (command line prompt).

Disable proxy setting:

@ECHO OFF

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Enable proxy setting:

@ECHO OFF

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d address:portNumber /f

address: New proxy address
portNumber: Port Number

Save the commands in a batch file and execute it. It will disable/enable the proxy setting for browser.

http://langbasics.blogspot.in/2012/11/disable-or-enable-proxy-for-internet.html